# How to find specific items in a CSV file using inputs?

Tags: python

I'm still new to python, so forgive me if my code seems rather messy or out of place. However, I need help with an assignment for university. I was wondering how I am able to find specific items in a CSV file? Here is what the assignment says:

> Allow the user to type in a year, then, find the average life expectancy for that year. Then find the country with the minimum and the one with the maximum life expectancies for that year.

```
import csv
    
country = []
digit_code = []
year = []
life_expectancy = []
count = 0

lifefile = open("life-expectancy.csv")
with open("life-expectancy.csv") as lifefile:
    for line in lifefile:
        count += 1
        if count != 1:
            line.strip()
            parts = line.split(",")

            country.append(parts[0])
            digit_code.append(parts[1])
            year.append(parts[2])
            life_expectancy.append(float(parts[3]))

highest_expectancy = max(life_expectancy)
country_with_highest = country[life_expectancy.index(max(life_expectancy))]
print(f"The country that has the highest life expectancy is {country_with_highest} at {highest_expectancy}!")

lowest_expectancy = min(life_expectancy)
country_with_lowest = country[life_expectancy.index(min(life_expectancy))]
print(f"The country that has the lowest life expectancy is {country_with_lowest} at {lowest_expectancy}!")
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a couple of rows of the CSV to your post.

Comment: Also, you are importing the `csv` module but not using it. See [how to read a CSV file](https://realpython.com/python-csv/#reading-csv-files-with-csv).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only want the first and fourth tokens from each row in your CSV. Therefore, let's simplify it like this:

```
Hong Kong,,,85.29
Japan,,,85.03
Macao,,,84.68
Switzerland,,,84.25
Singapore,,,84.07
```

You can then process it like this:

```
FILE = 'life-expectancy.csv'
data = []
with open(FILE) as csv:
    for line in csv:
        tokens = line.split(',')
        data.append((float(tokens[3]), tokens[0]))


hi = max(data)
lo = min(data)

print(f'The country with the highest life expectancy {hi[0]:.2f} is {hi[1]}')
print(f'The country with the lowest life expectancy {lo[0]:.2f} is {lo[1]}')
```